# replace HTTP requests on Android

Tags: android

I need to modify the HTTP requests issued by a 3rd party legacy library.

On iOS we had a NSURLProtocol that allowed us to take control of HTTP requests. On Android, is there something that does the trick?

Update:
The requests I'm interested to modify are browser requests for a web view.
What I need to accomplish are 2 things.
 1. Add headers
 2. Avoid cross domain request restriction problems. So, instead of requesting a resource like http://something.com/myResource.doc I want to provide a local copy of that file (embedded in the apk).

Comment: Are these web service requests, or browser requests for a web view?  And what do you want to do with them, redirect or add headers?

Comment: @GabeSechan: I upadted the main questin, thanks for your interest

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android