# how to modify the value of the key 'X-requested-with' in the request headers of resource request in Android webview, but not a page request?

Tags: android, ajax, ajax-request

I have met a problem when I capture the http package when my webView visit a url. the package shows that the request send by ajax has a 'X-requested-with' key in the headers, which has the value of my app package name like 'com.xxx'. I don't want the url I visited to know the request came from my app, so I need to replace the key 'X-requested-with' to another value.but I tried the sloution in [Add custom headers to WebView resource requests - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android), all of them do not work.

`loadUrl(Strring url, Map<String, String> extraHeaders)` will be called only in the page request, not in the resource request send by ajax.`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` and `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView view, java.lang.String url)` will be called in every request, but I can't modify headers in them.
So any solutions to the question? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

well, finally I solve the question. I can't find out the way to modify the headers in the request send by ajax in an loading page still, but I chose to override `public String getPackageName()` in `Application`. I look up the callingstack, if the calling comes from android.webkit, I return another string instead of my package name. So my issues solved. But the basic question still leaves.

Comment: i followed your advice but the app force closes when i override that method. Even when i only change the return string if the calling comes from android.webkit.
You didnt get an error when the webview is created?