# PackageName property override bug in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

[Attatched project file : http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45900/application-packagename-property-override-problem-is-this-xamarin-bug]

I tried to override Application PackageName Property. But java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError (Native method not found) occurred. So I search this problem in google, and I find a question about perfectly same problem(https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45434/application-packagename-property-override-problem). But unfortunately there was not an answer. What can I do this problem.

```
[Application]
public class TestApplication : Application
{
    public override string PackageName
    {
        get
        {
            return "com.fake.packagename";
        }
    }
}
```

error log

```
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): Process: TestApp.TestApp, PID: 25801
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: md5cf27010e14af20e69784a5a54418b85f.TestApplication.n_getPackageName:()Ljava/lang/String;
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at md5cf27010e14af20e69784a5a54418b85f.TestApplication.n_getPackageName(Native Method)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at md5cf27010e14af20e69784a5a54418b85f.TestApplication.getPackageName(TestApplication.java:25)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4855)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4476)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4413)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:142)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5120)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
07-17 23:06:57.179 E/AndroidRuntime(25801): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like both a limitation and a bug in MonoAndroid; the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception occurs because the method `n_getPackageName` has not yet been registered with the Mono runtime and fails to resolve. The short answer is:

- It's probably not possible to override the `PackageName` property for an `Application` because of complexities in MonoAndroids startup sequence.
- File a bug report with Xamarin. This a bug in the startup routine for MonoAndroid (Outlined below).

### Down The Rabbit Hole

Let's dig into the bridging Java code to determine why this happens. When you build a MonoAndroid application, a bunch of Java code is generated in the `[ProjectName]/obj/[Configuration]/android/src` directory of your project. This source code is the interop layer that allows applications built in C# to execute on an Android device via Dalvik or ART. Each class in your project that is an Android component (`Application`, `Service`, `Activity`, `Fragment` etc) will have a corresponding .java source code file generated.

This is the one for your `TestApp` class:

```
package md5cf27010e14af20e69784a5a54418b85f;

public class TestApplication
    extends mono.android.app.Application
    implements
        mono.android.IGCUserPeer
{
    static final String __md_methods;
    static {
        __md_methods = 
            "n_getPackageName:()Ljava/lang/String;:GetGetPackageNameHandler\n" +
            "";
    }

    public TestApplication () throws java.lang.Throwable
    {
        super ();
    }

    public java.lang.String getPackageName ()
    {
        return n_getPackageName ();
    }

    private native java.lang.String n_getPackageName ();

    public void onCreate ()
    {
        mono.android.Runtime.register ("TestApp.TestApplication, TestApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", TestApplication.class, __md_methods);
        super.onCreate ();
    }

    java.util.ArrayList refList;
    public void monodroidAddReference (java.lang.Object obj)
    {
        if (refList == null)
            refList = new java.util.ArrayList ();
        refList.add (obj);
    }

    public void monodroidClearReferences ()
    {
        if (refList != null)
            refList.clear ();
    }
}
```

The important things to note here are:

- The definition of overridden methods that link into your .NET assembly:

  ```
  static final String __md_methods;
  static {
      __md_methods = 
          "n_getPackageName:()Ljava/lang/String;:GetGetPackageNameHandler\n" +
          "";
  }
  ```
- The linkup code for your `PackageName` property.

  ```
  public java.lang.String getPackageName ()
  {
      return n_getPackageName ();
  }

  private native java.lang.String n_getPackageName ();
  ```
- And the registration code:

  ```
  public void onCreate ()
  {
      mono.android.Runtime.register ("TestApp.TestApplication, TestApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", TestApplication.class, __md_methods);
      super.onCreate ();
  }
  ```

Now, the most probable reason it crashes upon the `n_getPackageName()` invocation is because an `android.app.Application`s `getPackageName()` method is called **before** it's `onCreate` invocation.

If then you dissect `MonoPackageManager` and `MonoRuntimeProvider`, you find the cause of the issue:

MonoRuntimeProvider.java

```
@Override
public void attachInfo (android.content.Context context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo info)
{
    // Mono Runtime Initialization {{{
    android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo apiInfo = null;

    String platformPackage  = mono.MonoPackageManager.getApiPackageName ();
    if (platformPackage != null) {
        Throwable t = null;
        try {
            apiInfo = context.getPackageManager ().getApplicationInfo (platformPackage, 0);
        } catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // ignore
        }
        if (apiInfo == null) {
            try {
                apiInfo = context.getPackageManager ().getApplicationInfo ("Xamarin.Android.Platform", 0);
            } catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                t = e;
            }
        }
        if (apiInfo == null)
            throw new RuntimeException ("Unable to find application " + platformPackage + " or Xamarin.Android.Platform!", t);
    }
    try {
        android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo runtimeInfo = context.getPackageManager ().getApplicationInfo ("Mono.Android.DebugRuntime", 0);
        mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication (context, runtimeInfo.dataDir,
                apiInfo != null
                ? new String[]{runtimeInfo.sourceDir, apiInfo.sourceDir, context.getApplicationInfo ().sourceDir}
                : new String[]{runtimeInfo.sourceDir, context.getApplicationInfo ().sourceDir});
    } catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException ("Unable to find application Mono.Android.DebugRuntime!", e);
    }
    // }}}
    super.attachInfo (context, info);
}
```

MonoPackageManager.java

```
// ...
public static void LoadApplication (Context context, String runtimeDataDir, String[] apks)
{
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (!initialized) {
            System.loadLibrary("monodroid");
            Locale locale       = Locale.getDefault ();
            String language     = locale.getLanguage () + "-" + locale.getCountry ();
            String filesDir     = context.getFilesDir ().getAbsolutePath ();
            String cacheDir     = context.getCacheDir ().getAbsolutePath ();
            String dataDir      = context.getApplicationInfo ().dataDir + "/lib";
            ClassLoader loader  = context.getClassLoader ();

            Runtime.init (
                    language,
                    apks,
                    runtimeDataDir,
                    new String[]{
                        filesDir,
                        cacheDir,
                        dataDir,
                    },
                    loader,
                    new java.io.File (
                        android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory (),
                        "Android/data/" + context.getPackageName () + "/files/.__override__").getAbsolutePath (),
                    MonoPackageManager_Resources.Assemblies,
                    context.getPackageName ());
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
// ...
```

The cause of the crash becomes clear when you walk through the startup routine:

- Android loads the `MonoRuntimeProvider` class and executes `attachInfo`.
- `attachInfo` invokes `LoadApplication`.
- `LoadApplication` calls uses the Application contexts `getPackageName()` method.
- `getPackageName()` calls through to the `n_getPackageName()` method.

According to the docs for `android.app.Application`:

> **public void onCreate ()**
>
> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects **(excluding content providers)** have been created. Implementations should be as quick as possible (for example using lazy initialization of state) since the time spent in this function directly impacts the performance of starting the first activity, service, or receiver in a process. If you override this method, be sure to call super.onCreate().

Because an Applications onCreate is called after a ContentProviders onCreate, the native method won't have been bound by Mono and therefore can't be resolved! So there is the root cause of the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception.

To summarise, it's both a bug and a startup complexity.

Comment: In Activity case, registration code is called at static constructor and inherited PackageName property works well. If i modify apk file to call an registration code at static constructor like Activity, then there is no error?

Comment: No worries, I like solving a good problem; this one was a lot more complex than I originally thought ;)

Comment: Don't modify the apk; that's generally not good practice. Why do you need to change the return value of `PackageName`?

Comment: I want like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720059
The answer was overriding getPackageName in Application. It works well in Java as i wanted.