# Change getPackageName() in application for webview, work fine but

Tags: android, webview, webkit

the answer from [how to modify the value of the key 'X-requested-with' in the request headers of resource request in Android webview, but not a page request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720059/how-to-modify-the-value-of-the-key-x-requested-with-in-the-request-headers-of) works fine but I do not know how to know if the call of getPackageName() method comes from webkit or not. Here is my code:

```
package com.xxx.xxx;
import android.app.Application;

public class Global extends Application {

    private static Global instance; 

    public Global() { 
        instance = this; 
    } 

    private final String PACKAGE="com.webnews.appdirector";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPackageName() {
        return PACKAGE;  //this work fine, but how to know if is webkit callback ??? "instance" have mcomponentcallbacks set to webkit, but how to read it ???
    }
}
```

I could do with the debug "mcomponentcallbacks" of "instance" was well on "webkit" but I do not know how to read it.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

try check stack trace from thread:

```
    StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement element : stack) {
        System.out.println ("\t" + element);
    }
```

in result:

```
lsk.test.Global.getPackageName(Global.java:43)
android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:133)
org.chromium.base.BuildInfo.getPackageVersionName(BuildInfo.java:92)
org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupController.nativeSetCommandLineFlags(Native Method)
org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupController.access$700(BrowserStartupController.java:40)
android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:606)
android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542)
```