# Modify HTTP request header before sending any request

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, http-headers

In my chrome extension, I modify the header before sending any HTTP request, using `chrome.webRequest` methods. There must be a way to achieve the same functionality without using chrome.webRequest but I can't seem to find any. Could anyone provide me with viable alternatives for it so I can check and modify headers before sending requests?

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function (req) {
  var customurl = req.url.substring(0, req.url.indexOf('/embed/'));
  var customRefererObject = { name: 'Referer', value: customurl };
  $.grep(req.requestHeaders, function (headers) {
    if (headers.name == 'Referer') {
      headers.value = customurl;
    }
```

In addition, I am modifying the headers from an Android webview. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android) might be related.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.href

Have a look at this:
http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html