# Android WebView sometimes doesn't send request headers on initial page load

Tags: android, http, webview, header

I have a webview activity that loads a URL with a few custom request headers in its onCreate() method. The requirement is to pass the custom headers with the initial URL request. On a few devices, the webview stops sending the headers after the webview activity has been launched a few times.

For example, I have a HomeActivity which launches a WebViewActivity. After launching the WebViewActivity and navigating back to HomeActivity a few times, the WebViewActivity stops sending the custom request headers and this behaviour doesn't change unless I clear the application's data.

I have confirmed this behaviour using a MITM tool. The implementation is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("header1", "header1_value");
    map.put("header2", "header2_value");
    map.put("header3", "header3_value");
    map.put("header4", "header4_value");
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/mypath", map);

}
```

The above snippet executes unconditionally on every activity launch. However, the headers are not present in the actual request made by the webview. Also, the page being requested is a 303 redirect.

Comment: I think you can find your answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android

Comment: @MahdiKhardani this is a different issue. Here, the webview isn't sending any custom headers with the initial page request itself.

Comment: can't you clear the cache once you leave the screen

Answer (score 0):

If your **minimum API target is level 21**, you can use the [shouldInterceptRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) else you can use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))

With each interception, you will need to take the url, make this request yourself, and return the content stream:

Then:

```
WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.setHeader("header1", "header1_value");
            httpGet.setHeader("header2", "header2_value");
            httpGet.setHeader("header3", "header3_value");
            httpGet.setHeader("header4", "header4_value");
            HttpResponse httpReponse = client.execute(httpGet);

            Header contentType = httpReponse.getEntity().getContentType();
            Header encoding = httpReponse.getEntity().getContentEncoding();
            InputStream responseInputStream = httpReponse.getEntity().getContent();

            String contentTypeValue = null;
            String encodingValue = null;
            if (contentType != null) {
                contentTypeValue = contentType.getValue();
            }
            if (encoding != null) {
                encodingValue = encoding.getValue();
            }
            return new WebResourceResponse(contentTypeValue, encodingValue, responseInputStream);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
             //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
            return null;
        }
    }
}

//Where wv is your webview
wv.setWebViewClient(wvc);
```

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android)