# How to play a video in webview from a link which needs authentication?

Tags: android, authentication, webview, retrofit2

We have some videos hosted in our platform. Let's say `mydomain.com/no_auth_video_1` and `mydomain.com/no_auth_video_2`, for instance. Now we added a third video `mydomain.com/auth_video_3`, but this one can only be seen if you add some authentication headers to the request.

In our android app, we use a `WebView` to play these videos. We have this html template:

```html
<!-- html stuf -->
<video>
<source src="%videoUrl%"/>
</video>
<!-- html stuf -->
```

and once replaced the url, we load the html on the webview with:

```java
webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8")
```

This works great for the `no_auth` videos, but not for the video which needs the authentication. Looking for some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android), I found that we should override the `shouldInterceptRequest` method on the WebViewClient:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    String url = request.getUrl().toString();

    if (urlShouldBeHandledByWebView(url)) {
          return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }

    return getNewResponse(view, url);
}

private WebResourceResponse getNewResponse(WebView view, String url) {

    try {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = getMyAuthenticatedHTTPClient()
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        final Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

        return new WebResourceResponse(
                response.header("content-type", null),
                response.header("content-encoding", "utf-8"),
                response.body().byteStream()
        );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This works intended since the query for `mydomain.com/auth_video_3` is executed, and I can see that the info is retrieved properly with the debugger. **Problem** is that in the `WebView` the video isn't loading anyway.