# i want android webview data binding in mvvm pattern

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding, webview

i want android webview data binding in mvvm pattern

my code (view model)

```
  companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("loadUrl")
        fun WebView.setUrl(url: String) {
            this.loadUrl(url)
        }
    }
```

xml

```
<WebView
                android:id="@+id/webViewTerm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:loadUrl="@{signUpViewModel.url}"
                />
```

The binding was successful,

but I want to add an extra header , I don't know how to put the data I want in that object bound to the companion object

Could you give me a little hint for me?

Comment: What do you mean by extra header?

Comment: Extra header? Is it like `Header` then `Webview` vertically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android

Extra header here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass extra headers to your WebView tag. See the example below.

In your XML, add headers to your XML tag:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewTerm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:loadUrl="@{signUpViewModel.url}"
    app:headers="@{signUpViewModel.headers}"
    />
```

In your code:

```
 @JvmStatic
 @BindingAdapter(value = ["app:URL","app:headers"], requireAll = true)
 fun loadUrl(view: WebView, url:String?, extraHeaders:Map<String, String> )
  {
     view.loadUrl(url,extraHeaders)
  }
```

Comment: Cannot find a setter for <android.webkit.WebView app:headers> that accepts parameter type 'java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>'

If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.


I'm sorry, but I don't know what to do when I get this error

Could you help me a little more?

Comment: The binding adapter is taken from the viewbindingAdapter, and in singinupViewmodel, it is only mutablelivedata and livedata. by connect xml

Comment: I solved this problem. Thanks for your advice, thank you.